# Hi. I'm trying to make a note page, but I've run into a problem. Url-for is not giving the function what it needs

Tags: python, flask

`url_for('handle_logout')` and `url_for('new')` are all fine
This is all of the relevant code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{welcome}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="section has-text-centered">
      <h1 class="title is-2">Hi {{username}}!</h1>
      <a href={{url_for('new')}} class="button is-rounded is-outlined is-primary">Create a note</a>
      <a href={{url_for('handle_logout')}} class="button is-rounded is-outlined is-danger">Log out</a>
    </section>
    <section>
      <ul>
        {% for note in notes %}
          <li>
            <a class="button is-light is-fullwidth" href={{url_for('view',title=note.title,note=note.note)}}>{{note.title}}</a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

These are the important python functions:

```
@app.route("/view/<title>")
def view(title, note):
     return render_template("view.html", title=title, note=note)
```

and

```
@app.route("/notes")
def notes_page():
    notes = db.collection("Users")[username]["notes"]
    if username != "":        
        return render_template("notes.html", username=username, notes=notes, welcome=welcome)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
```

can you please help me? It would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So... what is the problem?

Comment: @AKX The problem is that url_for('view', title={{some_python_jinja_variable}}, note={{some_other_variable}}) in the HTML code doesn't work. It always tells me in the traceback that it's missing a required positional argument: note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL routing is

```
@app.route("/view/<title>")
```

and the function is

```
def view(title, note):
```

so either

```
@app.route("/view/<title>/<note>/")
```

or

```
def view(title):
```

...